# javascript 01.00 number manipulation

Tags: javascript, increment, decrement

I have an input with value 03.00 representing number of seconds.
I can't figure out how to make a function that will increment or decrement by one this number formatted like this.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `parseFloat()`, then add 1 and reformat the output.

Comment: A 'number' cannot be formatted like that, only a string can.

Comment: I've tried: `parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);` and after that used a function that was supposed to add a leading 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function inc(val, by) {
    val = parseFloat(val) + (by||1);
    return (val >= 10 ? '' : '0') + val.toFixed(2);
}
```

Decrement is just `inc(val, -1)` or create a wrapper;

Comment: @IulianMiu If it answers your question click the checkmark below vote count to make it entirely green ("accept answer").

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have an `<input>` with `id="myInput"`, you can use following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value="0"+parseFloat(document.getElementById("myInput").value)+1;
```